# Cypress wait for delay in text change assertion?

Tags: cypress

So Im curious if there is a good solution for this. I have a text field I am asserting on that it changes to a specific text after updating a form in a modal.

The problem is the text takes a good 2 to 3 seconds to change and the field is there beforehand so the assertion fails before it changes.

By default does Cypress "wait" when looking for text changes/assertions on text fields? (IE: `<element>.should('contain.text', 'Assertion text here!')`

or if it sees ANYTHING will it just do the assertion right away?

Im looking for a "smart" way to wait essentially instead of just `cy.wait(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the banner at the top of the documentation on `cy.should()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should):

> Assertions are automatically retried until they pass or time out.

By default, [Cypress commands have a 4 second timeout.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts) If your update consistently happens in under 3 seconds, you probably won't have to modify that value. But, if you needed to, you could modify that timeout value directly in the test.

```js
// below changes the timeout to 10s (10000ms)
// timeout is passed from cy.get to cy.should
cy.get('foo', { timeout: 10000 }).should('have.text', 'bar');
```

Comment: Hmmm it def. fails in under 3 seconds but I feel like it's getting a stale reference somewhere...maybe something to do with the modal still overlaying an element that it tries to check, ill try adjusting the timeout and see what happens.